# Suspend / disable a particular email account. Linux whm cpanel

Tags: linux, email, cpanel, brute-force, whm

My problem with one email account is not incoming / outgoing spam, that I could manage. It's the Brute Force attempts. My csf and cphulk take care of the attemps already, BUT its like 10 attemps per second from VERY different IPs. 
So only solution I can think of is temprorarily disabling / suspending the said email account. But I cant find a way to do this via whm linux or cpanel.

Apparently it's already a feature request for whm/cpanel: https://features.cpanel.net/topic/disable-email-account

The only thing i found close to a solution was this: http://cpanelplesk.com/disabling-an-email-account-in-cpanelwhm/

But I dont know if It would work, and if its the right way to do this. Any opinions ?

Comment: Even if you disable it, attack will continue and your server will report invalid username/password error so it will not help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable/suspend any single mail account on cpanel server, As per the above URL you can prevent outgoing email from the single account. But you are getting invalid login attempts issues so that will not help you on this.